# Is it "Vay-SHA-vucha" or "Va-YASH-vucha" in Anim Zemiros?

Tags: hebrew, song-poetry, pronunciation, nuschaot

Is it "Vay-SHA-vucha" or "Va-YASH-vucha" in Anim Zemiros? I've heard both, and seen both in different siddurim. Any insight?

Answer (score 2):

Vayshavucha is a simple verb, vayashvucha is causative.  So, from what I can tell, vayshavucha would mean the neviim directly "summed up" Hashem by describing his works.  Vayshavucha would mean the neviim described Hashem's works, and that caused Hashem to be "summed up".

In short, I don't see why someone should have an hakpada for one over the other.

Comment: It seems both words mean "they equated You" as a transitive verb referring to the human effort to express and comprehend God's actions metaphorically because He is by nature removed from direct observation. Most lines of the song are allusions, so perhaps even if the meaning would not change, a search for the precedent for these words could at least yield the word more likely intended by the author.

Comment: WAF, if you're saying that the author is alluding to a pasuk, that is significant and identifying the original form would be important.  If that's not what you mean, in what way would you distinguish between the two to say that the author favors one way over another?