# words often mispronounced

Tags: words, pronunciation, mistakes

What are some words commonly mispronounced? (Not by [elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision)/[reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction#Weakening_of_vowels) (like ה׳‎→אדְני‎) or [assimilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_%28linguistics%29) (like תזכרו‎→תשׂכרו‎), but rather words that are pronounced wrong simply because that's how people think they should be pronounced.) I'm excluding from this request errors in stress (emphasis), as those are, alas, too numerous to list. I'm *including*, however, words mispronounced in a person's own dialect (הברה), though others would consider them correctly pronounced. And I mean any "Jewish" word: a word relevant to, and mispronounced in, Jewish life, be it Hebrew, Yiddish, Aramaic, or other.

Comment: I like the allusion to vidui.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you mean by "pronounced wrong simply because that's how people think they should be pronounced". Are you specifying that the mistakes have to be due to whim or that they have to be due to conviction? Does it matter if people have divergent convictions depending on context? (The first divergence that comes to mind is between colloquialism and Torah reading of the "same" word.)

Comment: @R'IM, it was quite unintentional. @R'WAF, I guess I meant that people will pronounce them wrong even when asked to pronounce them carefully.

Comment: Are you also excluding mistaken dialects? i.e. correct (or I should say common) in a given dialect, but that dialect is not correct Hebrew?

Comment: @AviD, can you give an example?

Comment: @msh210, same as on the meta thread, I'm referring to yeshivish, and "Ashkenoizis" (as opposed to Ashkenazit...)

Comment: @AviD, I don't know why you're saying _havara Ashk'nazis_ is incorrect, but, in any event, yes, I mean to exclude things that are correct in _havara Ashk'nazis_ and used therein.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/

Comment: A shame you had to close this question. A popular question that received a lot of answers and the time and because it doesn't fit a standard that was made later on as to what should be asked here. I think mispronounced words is useful and a shame I can't add my own answers now.

Comment: I would add something that is maybe controversial but a dropped pronounced sheva when the next letter is an ayin, like Sab'-einu pronounced Sabeinu  like the ayin isn't there at all. And Korim in Aleinu. (should be Kor'-im)

Comment: @CashCow https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/960/9643

Answer (score 20):

A real big one: אלוה (with a patach under the hei) - many people pronounce it: elohah, while the correct pronunciation is eloah (like noach, and not nocha).

Comment: True. Also other words of the same mishkal, like גבוה (which they mispronounce in Lakewood for sure!).

Comment: @R'Alex, _gavoah_ is certainly mispronounced, but I don't _think_ it's the same _mishkal_ as _eloah_....

Comment: Same rule is true when the word ends in 'Ayin (Yodea').  People who are careful to pronounce every syllable individually but do not pronounce an 'Ayin as a guttural will very often insert a simple glottal stop in between the Tzereh and the Patah (Yo-dey-ah instead of Yodeya').  This drives me nuts.

Comment: @Seth: it's not so simple. Sephardim, who do in fact pronounce a guttural ayin (and het), insert an "extra" consonant before the patach ganuv (the technical term for it is an *epenthic* consonant), depending on the preceding nekudah: "w" if it was a cholam or shuruk, "y" if it was a tzeirei or chirik. Thus, "yode-ya'", "gavo-wah", "elo-wah", and so forth.

Comment: @R'Seth, see also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/2313.

Comment: Alex, as well they should. At least in my opinion.

Comment: That does not mean, however, that people should insert a glottal stop in between the letters.

Comment: Really, this is proof that Hawaii is one of the lost tribes, as it should be Aloha. Aloha has the same meaning of "Shalom", and is one of the names of Hashem :)

Comment: Hmm, I never tagged @Alex. Sorry about that!

Comment: The correct grammatical term for this phenomenon is the furtive patach

Answer (score 18):

Many, many kids when singing birkat hamazon out loud:

> "umeitiv lakol umeichin mazon **le'echol** b'riotav ..."

G-d feeds us so He can then eat us up?

Instead of:

> "umeitiv lakol umeichin mazon **l'chol** b'riotav ..."

The problem is the standard "benching tune" tends to push this one.

Answer (score 11):

Often the problem is we see a familiar-looking word and our brains assume it's the word we know, rather than sounding it out carefully as it may be slightly different. E.g. a word that looks just like "edosav" but is actually "edvosav."

The best example that I know of, though, is when the Chazzan takes the Torah back on shabbos; the congregation chimes in with "Hodo al eretz v'shamayim"; "His glory is on the earth and heavens ...". Unfortunately the word "hodo" is less common in our prayers than the word "hodu", *give thanks*; I usually hear about half the shul saying that. (Maybe it's just my hearing?)

Then there's the fellow who would do Psukei D'Zimra every day and say "v'yimalei ch'vodEE es kol haaretz, amen v'amen." ("may His glory fill the Earth" -- just with *my* instead of *His*.)  Heh.

Comment: Or the one who went "Orech yomim **asibehu**" instead of "asbiehu"

Answer (score 9):

"zecher lemaase **b**ereshit" in the "magen avot" of shabbos, should be "zecher lemaase **v**ereshit"

Comment: ...and many an initial ב or כ or פ or ת pronounced with a _dagesh_ when following a _mater lectionis_ in the same phrase.

Comment: ...like _Shaare T'shuva_.

Comment: See also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6958

Comment: Many Jews don't even have "vet refu'ah". I generally ignore it when that happens, as it doesn't change the MEANING of the word.

Comment: Even if it doesn't change the meaning of the word still it's a wrong pronunciation.

Comment: According to the Syrians is the correct way to pronounce it, and its Zekher or Zecher not Zeher. Zeher would be with a Heh or a Heth.

Comment: @H' Gabrial, I didn't knew how to transcribe that part correctly in English. I'll fix it. Anyway that wasn't the point.

Comment: Just for the future to know that the letter כ is always pronounced "CH" whether Sephard Ashkenaz etc. But the difference is the  ח between Sephardim and other Nushaot is that is it is a throat "Het" and for Ashkenazim it is the same as the  כ.

Comment: It is not important enough such that if one read in this manner during K'riyas HaTorah you would not correct them. Not sure about the Mi-chamocha / Mi-Kamocha in the parsha coming up this Shabbos (B'shalach)

Answer (score 8):

ספר  ישׁעיה פרק מ פסוּק לא וְקוֹיֵ ד' יַחֲלִיפוּ כֹחַ is often [mispronounced](http://torahmusings.com/2009/11/waiting-for-lord/) as וְקוֹוֵי ד' יַחֲלִיפוּ כֹחַ

Comment: Oh my gosh! I had no idea!

Answer (score 7):

"Rebbe" (or "Rebbi") is one. Depending on who you ask, the proper form is either רַבִּי (Ashkenazic), רִבִּי (Sephardic), or רְבִי (R' Yaakov Emden).

Comment: "Depending on _whom_ you ask" #irony

Comment: Rebbi is the Yiddish pronunciation, just so you know.

Answer (score 6):

One that I notice a lot is v'taher libeinu l'avd'cha (to your servant) instead of l'ovd'cha (to serve you).

There's also a bunch in "yeshivish dialect" that are to numerous to count (lichora, b'dieved, machmas, etc.)

Comment: I hear a lot of Americans brought up with the _Mizrachi_-style _havara_ pronounce many "o" _kamatz_es as "a".

Comment: @msh210, I know people who switched from Ashkenazi to American-Israeli who miss certain instances of kamatz katon. I use Ashkenazis but I try to differentiate

Answer (score 6):

Has anybody else noticed that many people attempting to sound "Israeli" or "Sephardi" often pronounce a Kametz as a Pata***h** even when it is supposed to be pronounced as a Kametz Katon?

Worst examples are:
"Kal" instead of "Kol" - I mean, come on, couldn't they at least pronounce it like Ashkenazim and say "Kawl"?

"Karban" instead of "Korban" - I have not heard many people make this mistake, but I have heard it a handful of times. It makes me cringe.

"Le'Avdecha" instead of "Le'Ovdecha".  :(

"Kadshecha" instead of "Kodshecha".  This one actually makes me want to cry.

Comment: Yep! This was already mentioned, too: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/5995#5995

Comment: "Kal 3atzmotai tomarna", "kal hamira", "kal nidre". There are exceptions, but bikhlal it should be "kol".
I know some Moroccans (including great Hakhamim!) who pronounce hataf qamatz as "ah", rendering total mispronunciations as "tzahala" and "tahara".
But what really irked me was when a ba3al qeri'ah was "corrected" to say "vayaQAM" in stead of "vaYAqom". MULTIPLE TIMES.

Comment: Actually, there is no Kametz Katon in Aramaic. However, as there is a difference between a Kametz and a Patah, when reciting a passage in Aramaic, it should be Kawl. Kawl Hamiraw, Kawl Nidrei.

Comment: @B.BarNavi, there's no such differentiation in Tiverian pronunciation, although that assumes that one differentiates komotz and patach

Comment: It is only Kawl if you pronouce in an American accent. I pronouce it Kol. That is different to the word meaning voice where the o is a bit longer (more like coal but not quite).

Comment: The 3 instances in Hallel. zochreinu is usually pronounced correctly and thankfully so is the second one so it doesn't sound like someone is using an obscene word in davening.. I often hear Chus V'Chaneinu though instead of Chus V'Choneinu.

Answer (score 5):

I'll start off with two:

- בָּתִּים (of תפלין) is commonly pronounced as if it were spelled בַּתִּים, even by those who distinguish the two.
- נַחוּם is commonly pronounced נָחוּם by those who distinguish the two.

Comment: Also דם, ים, and many other words containing a kamatz, which are pronounced as though they had a patach.

Comment: Re נחום, see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14139.

Answer (score 5):

In the Shabbos Davening there is often the word Shabbas which is mispronounced as Shabbos. For example באהבה וברצון שבת קדשך

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I should add another answer for this (or append to above ^^^)

Yontiff - as opposed to Yom Tov

Comment: Yontiff is already a recognized Yiddish word (at least according to someone on wikipedia!) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yontif

Comment: @Yahu Interesting. I always though it was a mistake. Wonder where it came from {eyes "Ask Question" button}

Comment: yydl, you are joking right? Of course it comes from a perversion of Yom Tov. So does Shaleshudos come from Seudah Shlishis.

Comment: Yeah. But still, it's strange how words come about just because they require less effort to say

Comment: That's by assimilation/reduction.

Comment: @Yahu - The סעודה שלישית --> _shalashudus_ shift has at least one more step in between, involving a shift in meaning, possibly with deep mystical roots (i.e. the 3rd meal actually comprising 3 meals).

Comment: Shalashudus comes from Shalosh Seudos, which is what Ashkenazim called Seudah Shlishit.  Obviously a Yiddishism.

Answer (score 5):

Bitya Bat Par'o instead of the common mistake of Batya.

Da-ni-yel  instead of da-ni-el

ברוך הוא אלוהינו שבראנו לכבודו should be pronounce sheb'ra'anu (that He created us) and not she'baranu (that we created)

and a biggie. people say Ha'shem (with segol) instead of Ha'sheim (with a tzerei) causing a subtle but fundamental difference in connotation between it sounding like a personification of a person's name (Hashem said this and Hashem did that) versus the way it should be taken, a non-physical third-person entity: THE NAME.

Comment: @DanielMokhtar, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for these excellent additions to this list!

Comment: Interesting points. But I don't understand the last one. What is the difference in meaning between "Hashem" and "Hasheim" (especially considering some don't differentiate in pronunciation between *segol* and *tzere*)?

Comment: kind of hard to explain in text. I think saying it verbally is the only way to sense the difference. The verbal deviation (of tzerei to segol) is only indicative of a more subtle transition of the word as a name of a person (hashem wants you to be good) when in fact it's meant as a description of an It (The Name wants you to be good). The difference is subtle but worlds apart in how one views the relation of man-to-creator imho.

Comment: @Isaac. Thanks for the welcome btw. יישר כחך on the site.

Comment: @Daniel, there's an dispute as to how to pronounce your name.  I've heard both ways.  According to my Tanach, it's supposed to be Dani-yel

Comment: @Zvi yes in my tanach as well. with a tzerei under the 'yud'.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14139/759

Comment: I pronounce tzerei like é, e with acute accent in French.

Answer (score 5):

The second pasuk in Sh'ma: ואהבת את ה' אל-היך... V'**a**-hav-**ta** should be pronounced mil'ra, not the almost universal "V'a-**hav**-ta".  This is serious, because it actually changes the meaning - it should mean "and you **shall love** Hashem your G-d", whereas the mispronunciation renders it "and you **loved** Hashem your G-d".  Reference: Rabbi Phil Chernofsky of [Torah Tidbits](http://www.ouisrael.org/tidbits/).

Comment: See the question: "I'm excluding from this request errors in stress (emphasis)". Note also that _v'ahavta_ with stress at the end as is proper is _mil'ra_ not _mil'el_.

Comment: Oops, editing my answer to milra {blushes}

Comment: I recognize the reason for the downvote, but given the importance of the placement of the emphasis, I'm giving it back an upvote.

Answer (score 5):

In Kaddish,

יהא שמה רבא **מברך** (Y'he sh'meh rabba **m'varach**)

is frequently mispronounced

יהא שמה רבא **מבורך** (Y'he sh'meh rabba **m'vorach**)

switching the kamatz for a cholam in "m'varach."

(In Ashkenazi pronunciation, I also hear "**m'voirach**" instead of "**m'vorach**."  Drives me crazy!)

Comment: When I read your answer, I said 'hey, that's what I say!'.  Actually, the first is a komatz and the second a patach, so (my)ashkenazic pronunciation would be m'vorach.

Comment: I think this could be because so many people who need to say Kaddish don't actually read Hebrew but instead use a transliteration, which, for reasons I still do not understand, use an 'o' for a Kametz when transliterating in Ashkenazi pronunciation. The 'oi' could also be an offshoot of that.  I've heard people say "Yisroyel".  -Shudders-

Comment: @YDK, edited to fix.  Clearly you can guess which pronunciation I use.

Comment: @SethJ, but I've heard this error from people who read Hebrew fine, pray thrice daily in it, and are responding to rather than reciting _kadish_.

Comment: So have I.  I've heard Mevoirach and Yisroyel from those who are experienced as well.  It's distressing.  I do believe it has much to do with the transliteration using an 'o' for a Kametz, whether or not people are using the transliteration or glossing over the Hebrew.  Once it's in their subconscious that Kametz is an 'o' it follows that some will pronounce it as such and that some will even pronounce it as 'oi'.  I've heard people accidentally pronounce a Tav as an 's' despite the fact that it has a Dagesh.  Usually this is corrected, as it's an accidental slip, not a regular habit, though.

Comment: I even heard someone give a speech on Shabbath Shuvah, who closed with "Ksiva vechesimah sovah." =:-o

Comment: @SethJ I heard a very, very famous speaker when speaking the Sefaradi Minyan say "tatut defut (mistake in the printing)" instead of "dfus" with a Samech :)

Comment: Um, @hachamgabriel hello... http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/13978/revisions. :-(

Comment: @SethJ don't feel bad, even that big speaker can make mistakes!

Answer (score 4):

I always cringe when someone replaces the "Ve" ("and"/flip to future) before a verb with the "Va" ("and"/flip to past) they're expecting.

One example of something similar: In Havdala (words are from Esther, but ba'alei keriya are less likely to make this mistake), saying "... vesasson vayekar" instead of "... vesasson vikar."

Comment: Isaac, check out my examples, some of which are just that.

Comment: Or vice versa.  One that throws me off if I'm not paying attention is וְיאמְרוּ בַגּויִם ה' מָלָךְ, since most times the word is וַיּאמְרוּ.

Answer (score 4):

Yeshivish types are trending from a-doinoi to a-dunoi to a-deenoi.

Comment: I recently read a quote from Rav Shimon Schwab ZT"L that said that pronunciation isn't Halachically valid according to any Ashkenazi minhag.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's my imagination, but I seem to hear people singing *v'nahapoch hu* (instead of *v'nahafoch hu*).

Comment: It's not your imagination. It is either their inebriation or their ignorance!

Answer (score 4):

bruchta, when people should say baruch ata H'

Comment: That's by reduction.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this question: [Why do many (most?) people call the upcoming holiday “Peysach”?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6576)

Answer (score 4):

The names of some letters of the alef-beis are commonly mispronounced, at least by Ashkenazim:

ב - with final /z/ rather than /s/
ד - with final /d/ rather than /s/
צ - with final /k/ rather than nothing (the proper name of the letter is "tzadi")
ת - with final /f/ rather than /v/

Comment: I wonder whether _tav_ → _taf_ is an example of a Yiddish tendency to devoice the end of a word, as in _yontif_ and _Hashem echat_ (yes, I've heard it). (Of course, that wouldn't help to explain _bes_ → _bez_.

Comment: "Beizmedrish". There's your answer: regressive voicing assimilation. Theoretically, once you take off the "medrish" you should be back to "beis", but for some it didn't work out that way.

Comment: [Later asked](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20545); [later asked](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22645).

Answer (score 3):

"דּוֹר לְדוֹר **יְשַׁתַּבַּח** מַעֲשֶֽׂיךָ" instead of "דּוֹר לְדוֹר **יְשַׁבַּח** מַעֲשֶֽׂיךָ" in אַשְׁרֵי
"

כִּי גָז חִישׁ **וְנָּעֻֽפָה** instead of "כִּי גָז חִישׁ **וַנָּעֻֽפָה**" in תְּפִלָּה לְמֹשֶׁה  in psukei dzimra of Shabbos.

"נְרַנְּנָה בִּישׁוּעָתֶֽךָ, וּבְשֵׁם אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ **נִגְדֹּל**" instead of נְרַנְּנָה בִּישׁוּעָתֶֽךָ, וּבְשֵׁם אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ **נִדְגֹּל** in לַמְנַצֵּֽחַ at the end of shaharis weekday.

"וְאוֹמְרִים **פְּעָמִים** בְּכָל יוֹם" as opposed to וְאוֹמְרִים **פַּעֲמַֽיִם** בְּכָל יוֹם before korbanos everyday.

**וָאֲהַלְלָה** instead of **וַאֲהַלְלָה** in אַשְׁרֵי

חַלָּמִישׁ **לְמַיְינוֹ** מָֽיִם instead of חַלָּמִישׁ **לְמַעְיְנוֹ** מָֽיִם in הלל

**וָאַשַׁלֵשׁ** instead of **וַאַשַׁלֵשׁ** in רבוֹן כל העלמים said Friday night before אשׁת חיל.

Instead of כִּי כָּל אֱלֹהֵי הָעַמִּים **אֱלִילִים**  I hear some people constantly say כִּי כָּל אֱלֹהֵי הָעַמִּים **אֱלֹהִים** in hodu of psukei dzimrah!

Even worse...
**וַיִרְאוּ** הָעָם אֶת ד instead of **וַיִּירְאוּ** הָעָם אֶת ד!

Can it get any worse? Yes! Baruch Hu Elokainu Shebaranu Lichvodo instead of Sheb'ra'anu Lichvodo!

and for now last but certainly not least one of my all-time favorites...

Instead of וּבָרֵךְ שְׁנָתֵֽנוּ **כַּשָּׁנִים** הַטּוֹבוֹת one guy I hear all the time says וּבָרֵךְ שְׁנָתֵֽנוּ **כַּנָּשִׁים** הַטּוֹבוֹת!

I have many more and can go on and on and on...

Comment: Retzeh in the admidah, the first uVIsfilosom is always pronounced usfilosom like the second one

Comment: Re למעינו, same thing with יֶאְשְׁמוּ (in Shabbos morning davening), and other examples where an aleph or an ayin has a sheva nach followed by a letter with sheva na.

Answer (score 3):

- I hear what sounds like hypercorrection of the o-->oy shift in the form of people pronouncing the words אויבים or אויבינו as אובים or אובינו.
- "Vay'hal'lu" in place of "viy'hal'lu" in "ויהללו ויברכו את שמך באמת" in the penultimate *b'racha* of *18*.

Comment: I've heard _go_ for _goy_!

Answer (score 3):

There is a phrase in the haftarah rani v' simchi [Zech. 3:7] וְנָתַתִּי לְךָ מַהְלְכִים, בֵּין הָעֹמְדִים הָאֵלֶּה  (MAHL'CHIM) that for a couple of years in a row I have heard MEHALCHIM.  Though I daven where they lein from klaf, so I don't know if that counts.

Answer (score 3):

Also words with an prefixed *bes*, *kaf*, or *lamed* with a *patach* (meaning "in the" or the like) pronounced with a *sh'va* (meaning "in" or the like), like *nogea b'davar*.

Comment: ...and occasionally the opposite, like _kav'yachol_.

Answer (score 3):

Also *l'y'rushalayim* (instead of *lirushalayim*) and similar: prefixed *vav*, *kaf*, *lamed*, or *bes* followed by a *yod* with a *sh'va* pronounced as two *sh'va*s rather than as a *chirik*.

Answer (score 3):

Jastrow notes that מחמת is actually מֵחַמַּת (mechamas) and widely mispronounced. (Thanks to [R' Micha Berger](/users/1570/micha-berger) for finding this confirmation of [my suspicion](/posts/6725/revisions).)

Answer (score 3):

עֲרָכִין‎ (the מסכת‎'s name).

Comment: That last one I'm not so sure about. Some mefarshim (will have to look up which ones) say that the proper name is indeed עִדִּיוֹת, meaning "the best" (paralleling the Aramaic name בחירתא by which the Gemara refers to it).

Comment: R'Alex, thank you for the correction; I'll remove _eduyos_ from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Often adopted by kids, or others who sing *birkas hamazon* emphatically. . .

> Hashem y'varech es amo **ba**shalom

as the last line, instead of

> Hashem y'varech es amo **va**shalom

Comment: You could categorize that as "Wrong application of the Beged Cefes BeRosh Milah Rule". (The exception is when it is when the word preceding it is a meshares [not a mafsik] and ends with an Alef, Heh, Vav, or Yud - Amo VaShalom is an example of this.)

Comment: See also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6095

Answer (score 3):

It drives me crazy when feminine nouns ending in a "saf" are pluralized into male form e.g. "tallis" => "talleisim" (should be "tallisos"), "shabbos" => "shabbosim" (shabbasos), "machlokes" => "machlokesim" (machlokos), and of course the most ironic "ta'us" = "ta'usim" (ta'uyos)!

Comment: Re _talis_ see http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol07/v07n039.shtml#14

Comment: ...who also discusses the others, actually.

Answer (score 2):

What about Shkoiach versus Yiyashar kochacho

Comment: Then the question is, what's the correct pronunciation? But that's another issue.

Comment: well shkoiach is meaningless

Comment: It's by assimilation/reduction, though.

Comment: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/7115/meaning-and-pronunciation-of

Comment: that should be "kochacha", as in "yours" not "his". But yes, I;m bugged by that one...

Answer (score 2):

There is another issue is with shva nah, it is commonly incorrectly pronounced in Shma.

Like "behol levovho uvhol nafsheho uvhol meodeho" instead of "uv**e**hol nafsheno uv**e**hol meodeho"

Also it sohuld be "sh**e**ma" instead of "shma"

Comment: jutky, whether it is uvchol or uv'chol is a machlokes and either are acceptable.  As for the rest, they're usually pronounced incorrectly by those who move the shva as well, as most who do so create a new syllable.  Which way is better, I do not know.  Btw, many people use an "h" to transliterate a "ches" which is a throat letter, but I have not seen it done for a "chaf" which is a palate letter.

Comment: Dittos on the "h" he'arah. Actually the Hes should be transliterated with an "h" with a dot centered underneath it.

Comment: @R'Yahu, as far as I know, there's no "should" in transliteration (unless you are subscribing to a particular scheme, in which case, obviously, you should follow that scheme). Consistency, legibility, and decodability are striven for, but do those imply a _ches_ __should__ be an _h_ with a dot beneath? Not IMO.

Comment: I should point out, as someone who tries diligently to use a bolded '*h*' wherever possible for *h*eth, that it's difficult to do these tricks when replying to posts on mi.yodeya.  I'm not sure if it's my HTML skills or the tools available here, but it ain't easy.

Just to advise jutky - it is very important to be internally consistent AND clear to others what your personal scheme is, which is not easy to determine within your answer.

Using an 'h' for a *H*eth and a Khaf, and also at the end of the word 'nah' is confusing. (I think you mean na' - with an 'ayin - not nakkkhh, am I correct?)

Comment: msh210, you are correct. I am referring to a specific scholarly theme that is commonly used in scholarly publications.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one has said this (maybe someone did and I missed it...): In *An'im Zmirot*, I hear a lot of people say *Vayashvucha* - וַיָשְוּוּךָ (they will compare you) instead of *Vayshavucha*  - וַיְשַוּוּךָ(they will imagine you)

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2879

Comment: I have seen both variants in sidddurim. Also Nafshi Chimda or Nafshi Chamda (but never the common Nafshi Chemda)

Answer (score 2):

I hear people say "Zachor et yom haShabbat l'kodsho" instead of "l'kadd'sho."  לקדשו with a kamatz instead of a patach.

Comment: Also often here in the y'hi ratzons "chochma" instead of "chachma". Word is spelt with a patach.

Answer (score 1):

"Shalashudes" to represent Seudah Shlishis. (I know it's supposed to be a form of "Shalosh Seudos", but firstly, it doesn't sound anything like, and secondly, it's the third meal, not 3 meals!)

Comment: Well... as a form of _shalosh s'udos_, the mispronunciation is by elision/reduction, which the question excluded (simply because cases abound, alas). And as a form of _s'uda sh'lishis_, I don't think it's a mispronunciation so much as a misnomer.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8754.

Comment: Likewise, a local Rabbi and a good friend of mine keeps saying "SeuDAT Shlisheet", as if the first was semikhut. Reb Artscroll says that the eating the third meal is as if you ate three meals altogether, citing Divrei Emes. Probably a retroactive justification more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

The bracha on spices is *'borei minei Vesamim'* not *'besamim'*.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6095 and its comments.

Answer (score 1):

אור Can be one of two words: "ohr" meaning light, or "ur" (or "eer" in hasidic havarah) meaning fire. These two meanings are different words and are pronounce differently, yet almost everyone I know always pronounces it "ohr", even when referring to fire.

Comment: nagah, thanks for this great answer, and welcome to the site: I hope you stick around end enjoy it.

Comment: I haven't met people who are _aware_ of this issue and yet mispronounce.

Comment: In l'cha dodi where the word Ori is followed by Uri twice, I hear Uri often for the Ori too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit off, but sometimes discussing the case of "Toveling a Toister"

Comment: I would add the conventional usage of " tovel" as a transitive verb in general. I "tovel", but I "matbil" a toaster.

Comment: @WAF: (I assume you don't mean that as an answer to this question about mispronunciations. In any event:) We do find _taval_ as a transitive verb: http://goo.gl/JLEa3.

Comment: @WAF See comments here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40144/759