# Pronunciation of the 3rd Shabbat meal

Tags: judaism

Are there any sources, sefarim, or rabbis throughout the ages discussing the name for the third Shabbat meal and the proper way to refer to it? I've heard variations like Seuda Shelisheet, Shalosh Se'udot, Shaleshsudis, Shalehsudis, and Shalushshiddius.

Comment: Sort-of a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8754

Comment: The last 4 (whichever are actually correct) are variations in pronounciation of the same thing

Answer (score 3):

The one word phrases are wrong. It's definitely a two word concept.

Seudah Shelishit means "Third Meal", Shalosh Seudos means "Three Meals"
Searching on Sefaria.com,. I can see the first term being used as early as Rambam to describe the actual meal, but the second term is used in the Gemara to indicate the mitzva to have thee meals.

If you ate an bentched on three pieces of bread friday night, would one of them be called Seudah Shelishit? perhaps only by those insufferable fellows who eat after Yom Kippur and call it breakfast.

Rambam calls the meal Seudah Shelishit in 1180. (Spanish, living in Egypt)
https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sabbath.30.9?ven=Mishneh_Torah,_trans._by_Eliyahu_Touger._Jerusalem,_Moznaim_Pub._c1986-c2007&lang=bi

The Shulchan Aruch (written 1565) calls it Seudah Shelishit. It's author was a Spanish Jew, living in the Galilee.

https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.529.1?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi

Shalosh Seudos is easier to combine into a single word phrase, it's not surprising that Yiddish speakers adopted this practice from Germans - to combine descriptors into a single phrase.

Perhaps to justify this lapse in language, it is said that this third meal is as significant as three meals.