# Why is it "Beiz"?

Tags: pronunciation, ashkenazi, aleph-bet-letters

I understand the Ashkenazi pronunciation of Hebrew is that the letter 'ת' with no דגש is an 's' sound.

So why do (many) Ashkenazim pronounce the name of the letter 'ב', which is normally spelled ב-י-ת (like the word for "house"), as "Beiz" (with a 'z' sound at the end)?

Comment: I think it's a Yiddish pronunciation.

Comment: I always heard "beis"

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6586

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I highly doubt there is any significance to such a pronunciation (although I stand to be corrected) but since you ask, here is a technical explanation (based on [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_s_sounds_like_z_in_some_words_in_English) and [here](http://www.rachelsenglish.com/consonant_zs)): There are two types of sounds - ones where you use your voice, like b, d, g, f and z, and ones where you don't like p, t, k, v, and s. The ones that you use your voice for are called *voiced* and the others are called *unvoiced*. The sounds "s" and "z" have identical mouth positions (the lips part and the corners pull back while the teeth themselves lightly touch). The difference is whether or not you use your voice when you say them. When a voiced sound comes before an "s", it often makes it sound like a "z". [For example: backs and bags. The "s" sounds like an "s" in backs because there is a "k" in front of it, which is voiceless. In bags, it sounds like a "z" because there is a "g" in front of it, which is voiced.] Since the *unvoiced* "s" in beis comes after the *voiced* "b" it can make it sound more like a "z".

Comment: +1 This also explains why we call the letter 'Tuf' when it should be 'Tuv' (or really, Tow).

Comment: The "ת'" doesn't come directly after the ב, so as far as I understand from the yiddish voicing rules, it shouldn't be voiced...unless--and I find this plausible--it is voiced from being voiced in "beizmedresh" (as suggested by comment here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6586/1516). @Michoel what do you think?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_voicing_and_devoicing

Comment: Are the f and v mixed up here? F seems unvoiced and v send voiced. Not that it matters too much to the answer.