# How to pronounce the name of the last letter in the Hebrew alphabet?

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters

I have heard mixed answers as to how to pronounce the letter **תּ**

Is it taf or tav?

(I'm referring to the halachic pronunciation not the common street way.)

Is there a difference between Ashkenazi or Sefardi in this matter?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6586

Comment: דל"ת is also pronounced דלד

Comment: `I'm referring to the halachic pronunciation not the common street way` What is an "halachic pronunciation" of a letter? AFAIK there are no halakhot or rituals concerning pronouncing the name of a letter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Talmud ([Shabbat 104a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=104&format=pdf)) spells it out as `תיו`. So anything from Taw to Tau to Tav is probably in the right ballpark. The unvoicing of the 'v' to make 'f' in common parlance is a common feature of speech (see also [this parallel question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20545/759)).

Comment: See [Yechezek 9:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1209.htm#4).