# Blessing on Immersing Vessels to Purify Them

Tags: halacha, blessing, mikvah-ritual-bath, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, keilim

A Mikvah can be used to purify humans or certain vessels which have contracted ritual impurity ([Rambam Mikvaot 1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a801.htm) ([English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1526065))).

When humans use the Mikvah to purify themselves they recite a blessing ([Rambam Berachot 11:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2511.htm#6) ([English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927679))).

Is there any recorded blessing to be said when immersing vessels to purify* them? What authorities support saying such a blessing and what authorities oppose saying such a blessing? What are their respective reasons? What is the text of the blessing?

Let's assume the vessels are being immersed in order to be used in a purified state, such as for eating sacrificial meat in the Temple.

* <sub>Note I am *not* referring to immersing food vessels purchased from a non-Jew as that immersion is not a purity-related concern ([Rambam Maachalot Asurot 17:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5217.htm#5) ([English](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968273))).</sub>

Comment: Why do you think Berachot 11:6 is limited to humans purifying themselves?

Comment: @Yishai For vessels it would be הטביל, though if you cite someone who claims otherwise that would be interesting although it wouldn't answer what the text of the blessing is or if anyone else argues.

Comment: @DoubleAA on a side note the Yersuhalmi Avida Zarah does hold the reason is tumah:תני רבי הושעיה צריך להטביל כהדא רבמי סלק עם רבי יודן נשייא לחמתא דגדר ושאלון כסף מן אילין דאוסינוס שאלון לרבי ירמיה אמר צריך להטביל לפי שיצאו מטומאת הנכרי ונכנסו לקדושת ישראל יצא לחוץ ונלמד נפקין ושמעון רבי יעקב בר אחא שמעון בר בא בשם רבי יוחנן לא שנו אלא לוקח אבל שואל מותר מעתה אפילו כלים רבי הושעיה זבין כלים ומטבילן.

Comment: @sam That's Tumah in a non-technical sense. The Yerushalmi is saying it's more like Gerut.

Comment: Several rishonim (e.g. Rif and Tosafos on *P'sachim* 7b) talk about a *b'racha* on *t'vila* applying to all "חייבי טבילות", and the Maharsha (*Chiddushei Halachos*, *Shabbos* 111a, s.v. בד"ה לא ס"ד) seems to include *t'vilas keilim* (of the type you discuss, as it's in the context of a discussion on טבילה בזמנה) in that category. I suspect that he would therefore require a *b'racha* of על הטבילה on impure *keilim* (though there is an opinion that this is the *nusach* in a standard case of טבילת כלים anyway - see *Or Zaru'a* 4:289).

Comment: @DoubleAA But must it always be הטביל for items? Regarding the אזוב, at least, the mishna ([*Para* 12:11](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%90)) follows the language of the verse ([*B'midbar* 19:18](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0419.htm#18)) and uses טבל. So perhaps the Rambam's language can be read as encompassing both people and vessels (even though הטביל would be more appropriate when referring only to items).

Comment: @Fred What form does the Rambam use in general (in Mikvaot, Keilim, etc.)?

Comment: @DoubleAA Where the Rambam discusses immersion as a transitive verb, the Rambam uses הטביל for immersing something else, whether *keilim* (e.g. [*Mikva'os* 6:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=11437) and [8:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=11466)), other people (e.g. [*Hil. 'Avadim* 8:20](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=13421)), one's body parts (e.g. [*Bi'as HaMikdash* 5:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=8031)), or even the אזוב ([*Hil. Para Aduma* 10:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=10057) and [15:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=10100))...

Comment: @DoubleAA But even when talking about immersing other things, the Rambam seems to switch to טבל if using it as an intransitive verb (see *Hil. Mikva'os* 3:[12](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Immersion_Pools.3.12/he/Torat_Emet_363), 18, and 20) and he may be using the word the same way in *B'rachos* 11:6. On the other hand, maybe Torat Emet's vowelization is wrong, and the Rambam is using *binyan pu'al* ("טֻבַּל"), as he seems to do in *Y'sodei HaTorah* 8:2 ("אלו ששולח להן") and *Ta'aniyos* 1:4 ("עד שירוחמו"). This may more neatly explain "כאילו לא **טבלה**" at the end of *Mikva'os* 3:20.

Comment: @Fred Pual is usually paired with Piel. In this case we have Paal and Hifil so I'd expect either Nifal or Hufal, but not Pual.

Comment: @DoubleAA If the Rambam wasn't using *pu'al*, then *Mikva'os* 3:12,28,20 seems like a precedent suggesting that the Rambam could possibly have used the intransitive *kal* in *B'rachos* 11:6 to refer to a category of immersions that includes *keilim*. | Note, BTW, that the *P'nei Y'hoshu'a'* ([*Beitza* 18a](https://books.google.com/books?id=vEovAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT311)) disagrees with the Maharsha (mentioned above) and says *t'vilas keilim* from *tum'a* is not a *mitzva* at all (possibly the [*Chasam Sofer* on *Nidda* 29b](https://books.google.com/books?id=9S8vAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA39) holds likewise).